# Facebook Graph API Explorer permissions not available attribution_read, public_profiles

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing an app and facing issues testing API calls in the Facebook Graph API Explorer. Some permissions are unavailable through the API Explorer, and I can only access them by creating a consumer or business app. Any advice on resolving this would be appreciated. I am unable to get `attribution_read` permission in both of them

```
Consumer App (Obtaining):
public_profile

Business App (Obtaining):
email
ads_management
ads_read
business_management
leads_retrieval
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_manage_ads
pages_manage_engagement
```

(Permissions I am Unable to Obtain):

attribution_read

My objective is to consolidate all these permissions into the Facebook Graph API Explorer to fulfil my need and don't get permission denied message during API call.